Have a few questions about a makefile that builds Fortran
I was wondering...
If you have to specify the MOD files in a clean target, or they get regenerated automatically anytime the .o is recompiled using gfortran (and mingw32-make). I suppose for a complete clean I should make them a target along with the .o files, yes? (Otherwise they could get stale?)
Do you have to specify a .MOD as dependent on it's corresponding .o to ensure it's rebuilt when need be?

Are you tied to make? If not my advice would be to use one of the more modern build tools such as meson or cmake

I would have the same questions regardless, with any of these build tools. All of my makefile building experience is with C.  This is the first time I've wanted to construct a proper build involving Fortran source specifically.

For meson at least (where I have more experience) it would work this all out for you, you just provide the source files. Cmake as well, I'm 99% sure.

Ok, I'll just have to look at the timestamps on the MOD files and see how mingw32-make handles it.

Make used manually is something you want to avoid for for Fortran. Use anything else. Something that prepares the Makefile for you, like CMake, or something completely independent, like meson, scons, fpm...

For the clean target, yes, remove also .mod files. And no, you don't need to put dependencies for the .mod files, they will be created when the source is compiled. You can state the dependencies between the .o files. For example, if file1.f90 contains a module mod1 used in file2.f90, you can do something like
file2.o : file2.f90 file1.o
   gfortran -c $< 

I think this is pretty common, but it does create unnecessary chains of recompilation. Here file2 will be recompiled every time file1 is changed, even if mod1.mod isn't updated (mod files are only updated if the interface changes).
But as the commenters write, it isn't easy to do anything better by hand, and CMake (with the make backend) creates a scheme with temporary files to to solve it. I would recommend Meson (+Ninja) if you are starting from scratch, it's great.
